# Simplest recursive SNARK working example

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, snarks

I have been doing some research into [recursive SNARKs](https://cs251.stanford.edu/lectures/lecture18.pdf). But I haven't found a working code example such as [this one](https://zokrates.github.io/gettingstarted.html#hello-zokrates) using Zokrates or this one using [snarkjs](https://blog.iden3.io/first-zk-proof.html). Anyone knows one such example, say, for proving a [hash chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_chain)?

Recursive STARK example is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for code that implements a recursive SNARK system, or code that implements circuits taking advantage of that (which is what you linked).

For code that implements zero-knowledge proof systems that support recursion, you'd have to look at [pickles](https://medium.com/minaprotocol/meet-pickles-snark-enabling-smart-contract-on-coda-protocol-7ede3b54c250) or [halo2](https://github.com/zcash/halo2/).

If you're looking at code that implements circuits that take advantage of recursion, there's some in [snarkyjs](https://github.com/o1-labs/snarkyjs/blob/main/src/examples/rollup/wip.ts) but it is not running in production yet. I'm not aware of anything else that runs in production (besides the circuits of Mina using pickles).